# Debian d-i preseed partman tmpfs

Tags: preseed, debian

I am trying to create automatic provisioning of my servers using pxeboot and netinstall. Everything works ok (RAID, LVM, ...), but I would need to create tmpfs for some directories.

I would like to use great option of partman - create partition that is as big as x% of memory. Therefore, for each server no matter how much memory it has, I'd like to use 20% as tmpfs.

Is that possible or I will have to create custom script and execute it as late_command?